# rostopic import error

Tags: rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the Ros Nodes tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes and have come across an error at point 6 in the website above^^.

When I try to run the '$ rosnode list' command in the new terminal window, I receive the error below:

import rostopic
ImportError: No module named rostopic

and therefore cannot continue the tutorial.

Has anyone overcome this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270893/rostopic-import-error/) by [danny5555](https://answers.ros.org/users/31904/danny5555/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-14**:
How did you install ROS? Are you `source`ing your `setup.bash` file?

```
source /opt/ros/<ros-version>/setup.bash
```

**Comment by [Hug](https://answers.ros.org/users/36570/hug/) on 2018-07-27**:
Can you see `rostopic` in the list when you type `python -m pip list`? You should also see other ROS-related modules such as `rosdep`, `rosbag`, ...

**Comment by [r.ghahremani](https://answers.ros.org/users/36906/r.ghahremani/) on 2018-08-09**:
Having same issue. any solution to this?
P.S, I install ROS as mentioned in DOCs. And I'm sourcing setup.bash (source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash). I also can see `rostopic` in the list when I run `python -m pip list` but some other `ros` stuff are there!

**Comment by [Hug](https://answers.ros.org/users/36570/hug/) on 2018-08-09**:
Have you installed conda? If so, you should comment or remove the line `export PATH="/home/<user>/<anaconda-version>/bin:$PATH"` in your `.bashrc` ([source](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs)).

**Comment by [r.ghahremani](https://answers.ros.org/users/36906/r.ghahremani/) on 2018-08-10**:
@Hug. No I did not install 'conda'. shall I? cuz there is noting about 'conda' in ROS documents as prerequisites as I know!!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-08-10**:
I believe that @Hug asked because many people have problems similar to this when they use Conda. I'd say that you probably shouldn't install it if you don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-rosnode

---

Originally posted by [Vishalyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/39692/vishalyo/) with karma: 16 on 2019-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0